# Assistance with SQLDataSource Filtering with Mixed Control Types

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been looking into DataSource Filtering and the complexity of my page app is making my logic wade through mud.

I have a Gridview that Displays 3/17 Values from a Datasource.
I want to run a filter on 3 DropDowns and 3 Checkboxes against the datasource. The 3 DDLs have a default value of String.Empty at Index 0 and are populated by another DS on Page load (!IsPostBack).

**My Issues:**

- When the page loads there is nothing in the gridview. Empty DDL Values should be skipped.
- The last check box should represent whether **(Part_Catalog.PartCount > 0)**.
- Currently filters are defined in the datasource, but due to the above conditions I need to do some processing in the cs file. What I'm unsure of is If I need to move the Entire DS to the code behind, the filters, or just the filter conditions.
- Also I'm not sure what events to wire into.

  ```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
       runat="server" 
       EnableCaching="true"
       DataSourceMode="DataSet"
       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:inventory_v2ConnectionString %>" 
                   SelectCommand="SELECT ID, OEMPartCode, PartCode2, UsedByOEM, ItemType, GroupType, PartCount, PartDesc, PartComment, PartMin, PartActive, MFRPartNumber, PartCapacity, PreTurnRequired, AssemblyPart, PartImage, PartImage2, NonInventoryPart FROM dbo.Part_Catalog"
                   FilterExpression="UsedByOEM = '{0}' AND ItemType = '{1}' AND GroupType = '{2}' OR     (UsedByOEM = '{0}' OR ItemType = '{1}' OR GroupType = '{2}') OR (UsedByOEM = '{0}' OR     ItemType = '{1}' AND GroupType = '{2}') OR (UsedByOEM = '{0}' AND ItemType = '{1}' OR     GroupType = '{2}')">
      <FilterParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="UsedByOEM" ControlID="DDL_OEM" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="ItemType" ControlID="DDL_ItemTypes" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="GroupType" ControlID="DDL_GroupTypes" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
      </FilterParameters>    
  </asp:SqlDataSource>


    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_OEM" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True"></asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_ItemTypes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True"></asp:DropDownList>   
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_GroupTypes" runat="server"   AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True"></asp:DropDownList>      
     <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="True" />
     <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
     <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Checked="True" />

  protected void BindOEMs()
  {
      SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["inventory_v2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
      connectionString.Open();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Manufacturer], [ID] FROM [Models_OEMs] ORDER BY [Manufacturer]", connectionString);
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      da.Fill(ds);
      connectionString.Close();
      DDL_OEM.DataSource = ds;
      DDL_OEM.DataTextField = "Manufacturer";
      DDL_OEM.DataValueField = "ID";
      DDL_OEM.DataBind();
      DDL_OEM.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, "0"));
  }
  ```

Comment: Where is the DetailsView in relation to this markup?  Also, it makes sense that the GridView starts out empty if those values in your GridView's datasource are never blank.

Comment: Added the GV definition, the Details View Definition and the DataSource that drives the Detail View. good point about the blank rows, I was wanting empty to equate to no filter.

Comment: I fixed the DV event firing. I had been setting it to visibile w/o checking for gv.selected index = -1. Still leaves check boxes and Blank DDL rows to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out now. I added the line below to page_load (!isPostBack) so filter applies at first load.

```
if (gvFilter.OEM == null || gvFilter.OEM == 0 ) { Filter_DataSet(null, null); }
```

Created a custom Filter object with my categories:

```
 public class Filters
{
    private int oem;
    private int item;
    private int group;
    private bool active;
    private bool ninventoried;
    private bool stocked;

    public int OEM
    {
        set { oem = value; }
        get { return oem; }
    }
    public int Item
    {
        set { item = value; }
        get { return item; }
    }
    public int Group
    {
        set { group = value; }
        get { return group; }
    }
    public bool Active
    {
        set { active = value; }
        get { return active; }
    }
    public bool Ninventoried
    {
        set { ninventoried = value; }
        get { return ninventoried; }
    }
    public bool Stocked
    {
        set { stocked = value; }
        get { return stocked; }
    }

}
```

Then I created a method to apply the filters to the Datasource and set all filter control events to this method:

```
protected void Filter_DataSet(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView1.Visible = false;
    string FEString= String.Empty;
    gvFilter.OEM = Convert.ToInt32(DDL_OEM.SelectedValue);
    gvFilter.Item = Convert.ToInt32(DDL_ItemTypes.SelectedValue);
    gvFilter.Group = Convert.ToInt32(DDL_GroupTypes.SelectedValue);
    if (CheckBox1.Checked == true) { gvFilter.Active = true; } else { gvFilter.Active = false; }
    if (CheckBox2.Checked == true) { gvFilter.Ninventoried = true; } else { gvFilter.Ninventoried = false; }
    if (CheckBox3.Checked == true) { gvFilter.Stocked = true; } else { gvFilter.Stocked = false; }

    if (gvFilter.OEM >0)
    {
        FEString += "UsedByOEM = " + gvFilter.OEM.ToString(); 
    }
    if (gvFilter.Item > 0)
    {
        if (FEString.Length > 0) { FEString += " AND "; }
        FEString += "ItemType = " + gvFilter.Item.ToString();
    }
    if (gvFilter.Group > 0)
    {
        if (FEString.Length > 0) { FEString += " AND "; }
        FEString += "GroupType = " + gvFilter.Group.ToString();
    }
    if (gvFilter.Active == true)
    {
        if (FEString.Length > 0) { FEString += " AND "; }
        FEString += "PartActive = " + gvFilter.Active.ToString();
    }
    if (gvFilter.Active == false)
    {
        if (FEString.Length > 0) { FEString += " AND "; }
        FEString += "PartActive = " + gvFilter.Active.ToString();
    }
    if (gvFilter.Ninventoried == true)
    {
        if (FEString.Length > 0) { FEString += " AND "; }
        FEString += "NonInventoryPart = " + gvFilter.Ninventoried.ToString();
    }
    if (gvFilter.Ninventoried == false)
    {
        if (FEString.Length > 0) { FEString += " AND "; }
        FEString += "NonInventoryPart = " + gvFilter.Ninventoried.ToString();
    }
    if (gvFilter.Stocked == true)
    {
        if (FEString.Length > 0) { FEString += " AND "; }
        FEString += "PartCount > 0 ";
    }
    //if (gvFilter.Stocked == false)
    //{
    //    if (FEString.Length > 0) { FEString += " AND "; }
    //    FEString += "PartCount <= 0 ";
    //}
    SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = FEString;
}
```